# Water simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm having trouble creating a water simulation. I want to create a short video of water flowing through a pipe for a product that i want to build and market. Anyway, to create this in Blender, I first created a domain, then to build the pipe I added a curve>circle, then added curve>bezier. I used the circle to bevel the bezier to form the pipe. I added a solidify modifier to give the pipe walls some thickness. I then added a uv sphere and placed it inside the pipe as my inflow. The problem is when I start the bake no fluid is created. if I raise the inflow so that it is outside of the pipe the fluid is created. Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps follow some simple tutorials? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdUWqkqcxzw

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't relate. My inflow is inside a pipe. As my question states I can create fluid outside of the pipe but not inside it.

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry. I just thought that having done the basics would help with the pipe as well. You may get better results if you right click the bezier-curve and convert it to mesh. But yeah, may not help with the inflow-problem. :/

Comment: Damn it! Forgot to do that. I'll give it a try and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: Tried converting the 'pipe" to a mesh. Now fluid is created but it blasts through the pipe as if the inlet pressure is 10,000 psi (set the flow for 30, as I need it to flow up in the z direction). It's as if the "pipe" is a soaker hose!